# Formik Yup `.test()` custom validation is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I created a custom Yup validation using `.test()`.

```
// users is an array of strings
user: Yup.string().test(
  "user-check",
  "At lease one user should be added",
  () => users.length > 0
)
```

The goal is to validate the form when at least one user is added. An input field let you type a username (any string value) then you click a button to add it to a list.

The validation is working well after adding the 2nd username (or adding the 1st one then start typing on the field).
I'm sharing this live Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-goldwasser-shpbk

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Click on the text field.
2. Type a username.
3. Click the red button.

**Expected**

- The form should be valid.

**What you'll get**

- The form is invalid

Any feedback about this strange behavior?

**Remark**

- I'm not sure if this is the origin of the problem.
- The first time you add a user, the validation is called 2 times: the 1st time with an empty `users` array and then with the correct `users` value (which is the user you added)!

Answer (score 2):

The scope of your Formik form currently contains only the input field for a user. The array with users is currently not part of your form (not included in the initial values). There are two things you could do:

- Move users array into your Formik scope. Work with `FieldArray` (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray) for example. Then you can do the validation like you try to do now.
- Do the validation manually when running `onSubmit`. For example like this:

```
  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (users.length > 0) {
       // there are some users (form is valid) -> do API call or whatever necessary
    } else {
       // no users (form is not valid) -> display some error
    }
  };
```

You could even just disable the submit button like this (even if it's not the correct way if working with Formik):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={users.length === 0} />
```

I hope this helps. If you have any questions, let me know and I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
user: Yup.string().test(
  "user-check",
  "At lease one user should be added",
  async (users) => await users.length > 0
)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This should be a comment to the original question. But I don't think it really hits the nail on the head though.